# Updating enum in Rails ActiveRecord model by end user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

Looking for the best strategy in the following scenario.

Consider Rails 4 online store app that has model Order that has a status

```
class Order 
  enum status: [ :placed, :processed, :shipped ]
end
```

We ship the app to the customer and a month later they come back to us saying the want to add one more status - backordered. We go in and update code / test / and deploy.

```
class Order 
  enum status: [ :placed, :processed, :shipped, :backordered ]
end
```

A few months later they come back again and want one more status - :work_in_progress . Etc

In the past we avoided the problem by having an aggregate model - Status - that would be an STI model and hold things like

```
OrderStatus < Status
```

and

```
CustomerStatus < Status
```

This makes is trivial for customer to add  statuses or change names of the status, but it makes for slower SQL look ups and cumbersome joins especially on complex queries.

So I was wondering is there a good strategy of dealing with this problem? Right now we have a combination of two - on the model we don't think customer would want to add / remove status - we keep it enum, otherwise we do belongs_to to a some kind of Status / Category model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *a month later they come back to us saying the want to add one more
>   status*

Changing one line of code, even if it happens once a month, should not be a painful experience. You already have the best strategy: when the customer asks for a change, grit your teeth, add the new value, test and deploy. If that is too onerous I'd say the problem lies with the deployment process rather than the customer.

After a few rounds of this the customer will run out of new values to add and move on to other annoying requests.

Comment: :-) I guess I was too specific. Let's say you are creating an open source rails store app, that's going to be used by hundreds of users. Or your customer doesn't want to come back to you for every little thing. I'm more a of a programmer than a people person in this case - I'd rather not deal with a customer for something as trivial as adding a new status. My gut feeling is there is gotta be a better way. No?

Comment: Fair enough. Your alternate approach is the one I would use if the changes are frequent or numerous. I see no magic bullet here: you trade the simplicity of the enum for the more complex model association and need to validate/sanitize user input.

Comment: That's the logical conclusion I came to. I guess my gut was wrong. :-) Just wanted to check it. I'll leave it open for a few days and if noone comes up with a better suggestion will mark it answered. Thanks zetetic

Comment: For posterity: I ended up going with a mixed approached some are defined as enums and some are defined in a db.